# Save/Load function in C language

Tags: c, save, load

I am working on a game program that requires me to save a 2D array into a file, and then if the user wants to go back to that game then can load it back up and continue it. But I am having a problem with getting the array to save into a txt file. And for the load function, it is not being able to load anything. The user is supposed to select the load option and it should be able to call the txt file with the array and then allows them to continue playing the game.

This is my save function

```
void save(char *filename)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "wb");
    fwrite(&size, sizeof(size), 1 , fp);
    fwrite(board, sizeof(int), size, fp);

    if(fp == NULL)
        return;

    fclose(fp);
}
```

This is my load function

```
  void load(char *filename)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
    fread(&size, sizeof(size), 1 , fp);
    fread(board, sizeof(int), size, fp);

    if(fp == NULL)
        return;

    fclose(fp);
}
```

Later in the code, I use a menu to call these functions.
Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Use `rb` mode when loading.

Comment: You forgot to close the file in `load()`.

Comment: "having problems" doesn't tell us what you are having problems with. Please provide a [mre], describe a specific issue and ask a specific question.

Comment: How is `size` related to the array size declaration?

Comment: @Barmar the size is the size of the 2D array for example is it going to be a arr[4][4] or arr[7][7].

Comment: @kaylum I have updated it if that helps

Comment: If it's `int arr[4][4]` do you set `size = 16`?

Comment: `int **board` is not the same as `int board[4][4]`

Comment: `int **board` declares an array of pointers. You can't write pointers to a file.

Comment: It is supposed to save a range of 2D arrays, a [2][2] all the way up to [10][10]. So that is why I have a pointer pointer so that it gives me the option of doing that.

Comment: @Barmar How would I go about properly doing these both? Because I feel like I am going in the wrong direction and I would like to better understand this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`board` is not a 2D array, it's an array of pointers to rows. You need to loop over it, writing and reading each row separately.

Since the size of the board being loaded may be different from the board currently in memory, you need to free the old board and re-allocate the new one when loading.

```
void save(char *filename)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if (!fp) {
        perror("Can't open save file");
        return;
    }
    fwrite(&size, sizeof(size), 1 , fp);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        fwrite(board[i], sizeof(*board[i]), size, fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

void load(char *filename)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!fp) {
        perror("Can't open save file");
        return;
    }
    if (board) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            free(board[i]);
        }
        free(board);
    }
    fread(&size, sizeof(size), 1 , fp);
    board = malloc(size * sizeof(*board));
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        board[i] = malloc(size * sizeof(*board[i]));
        fread(board[i], sizeof(*board[i]), size, fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, write `RB` while loading. Second, don't forget to close all of the files after entering the `FILE` command.

Additionally, I have advice for you: Always check if `*fp` is equal to `NULL`; it's great for debugging and can have huge impact on your code. You can also write a function for multiple checking while using file in your program.

Comment: So I should put an if statement checking if it is NULL.
like this
if *fp == NULL
return 0;

Comment: Yes.Always good for debugging and knowing if your input is invalid.

Comment: These are all good points, but probably not the problem he's having.

Comment: Yes, thank you @OriBashary I will use this in the future. But when I compile it I am getting this error
invalid operands to binary expression ('FILE' (aka 'struct __sFILE') and 'void *')

Comment: You should be checking `fp`, not `*fp`.

Comment: @Barmar should that be in both save and load?

Comment: @JoeLaBianca Of course. If you can't open the file, you can't continue with either.